# Use args for all views w/o repeating it django

Tags: django, view

I have faced one problem in django views. I'm getting categories for my menu, like:

```
args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.filter(category_language=4).order_by('id')
```

so let's say, I have

1. Homepage View
2. Article List View
3. Article View

And so on...

And the problem is that I have to write:

```
args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.filter(category_language=4).order_by('id')
```

for all views and if I exclude some categories from this list then I have to make changes for all views

How can I use args once for all views?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to make your categories available in templates, then I'd recommend using a ContextProcessor for that: See [Dajgno Documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

However, if you would like to just include them in all your views for some other reason, then I'd use a mixin. See [Django Documentation again](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/)

Here is a sample mixin I that inherit in all of my views:

```
class BlogPostMixin(View):
    """
    A mixin that renders BlogPost form on GET request and processes it on POST request.
    """

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ this is fired up first regardless of what http method is used """
        return super(BlogPostMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #context = RequestContext(self.request)
        context = super(BlogPostMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['form'] = kwargs['form']
            context['attachment_form'] = kwargs['attachments_formset']
            context['attachment_helper'] = AttachmentFormsetHelper()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        return context
```

I use this mixin in my view like:

```
class BlogPostUpdateView(BlogPostMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    A view that updates existing blogposts. The form_valid and form_invalid methods
    are handled in in BlogPostMixin because that code is shared between this view and
    the CreateView for blogpost.
    """
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    template_name = 'blog/blogpost_form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(BlogPostUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is related with filtering categories in database, you can just extend your `ArticleCategory` model manager:

```
from django.db import models


class ArticleCategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def for_menu(self, model):
        return self.filter(category_language=4).order_by('id')


class ArticleCategory(models.Model):        
    objects = ArticleCategoryManager()
```

Then you will need only to write:

```
args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.for_menu()
```

and don't care about how they are actually retrieved. If you need to change the logic of getting them - you change it only in one place - in manager's method.

As about repeated arguments - I don't see a problem in it because there is only one argument and three views, in case of bigger amount use a mixin or helper method to get that set of arguments.

**P.S.** A little recommendation - do not use hardcoded magic numbers, like `4`, use constants instead.

Answer (score 0):

Believe, there are 3 things that can be improved:

- Avoid repeating the same code in views. You have to implement [Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) to add appropriate functionality to your Views
- Move filter() logic to the appropriate Manager method:

  ```
  class ArticleCategoryManager(models.Manager):
      def menu_categories(self, model, language = 4):
          return self.filter(category_language=language).order_by('id')

  class ArticleCategory(models.Model):
      object = ArticleCategoryManager()
  ```

To use default language id:

```
args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.menu_categories()
```

To explicitly set language:

```
args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.menu_categories(language=4)
```

- Replace 4 with a constant: it difficult to read such code & you have to spend some time to understand the meaning of this value.

  Example of implementation:

  ```
  class ArticleCategoryLanguage(object):
      GERMAN = 3
      ENGLISH = 4

      LANGUAGES = (
          (GERMAN, 'German'),
          (ENGLISH, 'English')
      )
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  args['categs'] = ArticleCategory.objects.menu_categories(language=ArticleCategoryLanguage.ENGLISH)
  ```